# Changing items in TTLauncherView according to TabBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, three20

I'm developing an iPhone application using the Three20 library. The main screen is a TTLauncherView (with images inside, like Facebook) and a TabBar at the bottom. Each time a new item is selected in the TabBar, I have to change the images inside my TTLauncherView.

I thought that I only had to change the "pages" property of my TTLauncherView, but it doesn't work. Nothing is displayed.

What am I doing wrong ? Is there a way to achieve this simple task ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not simple. You have to create multiple TTLauncherView to populate into your TabBar view controllers, not by changing the pages property.

Comment: I suspected this, but I was not sure. Thank you very much